# Why does it appear that my Golang server has persistent memory usage?

Tags: go, concurrency

Hopefully someone can clear this up. I am writing a recursive crawler, that when complete, returns a JSON string. At first, I thought it was my code in the master project, so I created a bare bones program to isolate and illustrate the issue.

When the below code is executed, it starts a server on port 8080, which delegates 1.1MB of RAM in my Activity Monitor. Everything ok so far..

When you curl that address, i.e. `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`, the handler executes by calling the given domain 2000 times. Once the go routines complete, it sends back a canned response. HOWEVER, the activity monitor now reads 29.9MB!? Shouldn't it go back down to 1.1MB because it is no longer operating? This has been driving me crazy, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the dummy program:

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "sync"
)

func main() {

log.SetFlags(log.Ldate | log.Ltime | log.Lshortfile)

http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 2000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            r, err := http.Get("http://theswellcompany.com")
            if err == nil {
                fmt.Println(r.StatusCode)
                err := r.Body.Close()
                if err != nil {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "test/html; charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string("DONE, but if it's done, WHY does the actvity monitor on my mac still read 40MB??"))
})

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: No, the memory is not immediately returned to the OS. Even if the memory is eventually freed by the runtime, it's only advisory, and if there's no memory pressure the OS isn't guaranteed to ever release it.

Comment: Are you saying this is the normal modus operandi? Is there a way to manually free the memory without calling os.Exit?

Comment: It's not necessary or beneficial to manually force memory to be freed, and it still doesn't gaurantee that the OS will reclaim it unless it's actually needed by another process. That's just how OS memory management works, and it's not something to be concerned about and does not require any "fix". If you have continuously increasing memory usage or crashes due to insufficient memory, that's a different matter entirely, but this sounds like completely normal memory handling.

Comment: [Here it is](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14521#issuecomment-189244596) from Dave Cheney himself.